# Jasmine test doesn't reach subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to write unit test in Jasmine and I have issues with testing the subscribe after the dialog opens. My test looks like this:

```
it('should open pop up', () => {
    const openDialogSpy = spyOn(component.dialog, 'open').and.returnValue({
        afterClosed: () => of(false)
    });

    component.onClickNewUser();

    const parameters= {
        id: 0,
        name: 'banana'
    };

    expect(openDialogSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        AddUserDialogComponent,
        {
            data: parameters 
        }
    );
});
```

And it passes and everything is okay. But when I run code coverage I see that it didn't reach the subscribe [code coverage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZRQT.jpg)

Is there a way for me to test this part as well??

Answer (score 0):

The `filter(id => id)` is blocking the emission of `of(false)` since this filter will only allow truthy emissions.

To reach the subscribe, you can return `of(true)`.

```
const openDialogSpy = spyOn(component.dialog, 'open').and.returnValue({
        afterClosed: () => of(true) // change this from false to true
    });
```